# Longvarchar in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot

This is the property,

```
@Column( name = "description")
private String description;
```

This is MySql Table
[image]

During compiling this error is thrown,

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [description] in table [product]; found [longtext (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]

What I am missing?

Comment: What are your `hbm2ddl` settings in `application.properties`?

Comment: @Jan Halasa, hbm2ddl is Validate.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can either modify the database:

```
ALTER TABLE product MODIFY description VARCHAR(255);
```

This simple `ALTER TABLE` command may fail if the description values are longer than 255 characters, so you may need to do it by creating a new column and transforming the values and dropping the original column.

Or you can adjust the Java code:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "description", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
private String description;
```

You can try to omit the `columnDefinition` first, it may be the default MySQL text LOB for Hibernate.

Answer (score 14):

I used @Type (org.hibernate.annotations.Type;) it worked

```
`addresses` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL

@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
@Type(type = "text")
private String addresses;
```

Comment: What if `found [mediumblob (Types#LONGVARBINARY)], but expecting [longtext (Types#LONGVARCHAR)]`

Answer (score 0):

For me, works

```
@Column(name = "DeckName", n`enter code here`ullable = true, columnDefinition = "nvarchar(MAX)")
```